# .animate not working - need duration?

Tags: jquery

The following JQuery animation is not working within another function:

```
$('navigation').animate({left: '+=500'});
```

Is it because I did not call a duration to it?

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Did you try adding a duration? It would have been quicker then writing this question.

Comment: Or maybe because you forgot to put in # or . before "navigation" ?

Comment: The animation duration is optional, it falls back a default of 400ms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The selector is not correct. You're selecting `<navigation>` elements. Probably you mean `$("#navigation")` - this will select the element with the ID `navigation`.

The duration [is not a required argument](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> Durations are given in milliseconds; higher values indicate slower
>   animations, not faster ones. **The default duration is 400 milliseconds.**

Comment: Thanks @pimvdb you were right about the period - But how come when you are adding a class (.addClass(example);) you don't use a period in front of it?

Comment: @Joe Isaacson: Whatever you pass as `...` in `$("...")` is a *selector*, which can be an ID (`#something`), a class (`.something`), and a lot more, even combinations of those. With `addClass`, you are not selecting but adding a class - so there is no need specifying a class selector period.